# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP - Tomcat 7

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

[image: This image description problem]

> I have a file jsp. when run file jsp with tomcat7, it show problem

```
An error occurred at line: 11 in the jsp file: /topics.jsp
n cannot be resolved
8:  PropertiesConfiguration keywords = new PropertiesConfiguration();
9:  keywords.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);
10:     keywords.setEncoding("UTF8");
11:     keywords.setPath(n.props("crawler_config_file"));
12:     keywords.load();
13:     keywords.setReloadingStrategy(new FileChangedReloadingStrategy());
14:     String id = request.getParameter("id") == null ? "" : request.getParameter("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
11:     keywords.setPath(n.props("crawler_config_file"));
                         ^
```

The variable `n` is not declared. This is an error in your code.

Comment: @DuyTư Do not edit my post to add information to your question. EDIT YOUR QUESTION to include the additional information